# Pass drawable image to TypedArray in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am trying to implement a segmentated radio button from here: https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton but I need to set the image programmatically and not in XML.

This is the source of the custom RadioButton:

```
public class CenteredImageButton extends RadioButton {

    Drawable image;

    public CenteredImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CompoundButton, 0, 0);
        image = a.getDrawable(1);
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.id.empty);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (image != null) {
            image.setState(getDrawableState());

            // scale image to fit inside button

            int imgHeight = image.getIntrinsicHeight();
            Log.d("IMAGEHEIGHT", "imageWidth is " + imgHeight);

            int imgWidth = image.getIntrinsicWidth();
            Log.d("IMAGEWIDTH", "imageWidth is " + imgWidth);

            int btnWidth = getWidth();
            Log.d("BUTTONWIDTH", "buttonWidth is " + btnWidth);
            int btnHeight = getHeight();
            Log.d("BUTTONHEIGHT", "buttonHeight is " + btnHeight);

            float scale;

            if (imgWidth <= btnWidth && imgHeight <= btnHeight) {
                scale = 1.0f;
            } else {
                scale = Math.min((float) btnWidth / (float) imgWidth,
                        (float) btnHeight / (float) imgHeight);
            }

            Log.d("SCALE", "scale is " + scale);

            int dx = (int) ((btnWidth - imgWidth * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);
            Log.d("DX", "dx is " + dx);
            int dy = (int) ((btnHeight - imgHeight * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);
            Log.d("DY", "dy is " + dy);

            image.setBounds(dx, dy, (int) (dx + imgWidth * scale),
                    (int) (dy + imgHeight * scale));

            image.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

I am setting the drawable in another file like this:

```
private void setButtonImageProperties(RadioButton button,Drawable drawable){
    button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Resources resources = this.context.getResources();
    float dipValue = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            60, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    float dipValue1 = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    button.setMinHeight((int) dipValue);
    button.setMinWidth((int) dipValue1);

    button.setButtonDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Please anyone, advise. I really need helping hand. Thanks.

Comment: I just need a way for the image to be called or referenced by the CenteredImageButton class..any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much need to add a setImage method to CenteredImageButton:

```
public void setImage(Drawable newImage) {
    image = newImage;
}
```

And just call it later in your main code:

```
button.setImage(drawable);
```

See this Gist to see the method inline: https://gist.github.com/1470789

I also noticed you changed the name of my class from CenteredRadioImageButton to CenteredImageButton. If you're not actually using this for the RadioButton-like behavior, I would suggest using a standard [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

(I am the maintainer of [SegmentedRadioButton](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton))